# sum of numbers given date of birth in dialog box

Tags: java

The point of this question was to get a dialogue box open, have it ask your name and date of birth in yyyy format; then give you the sum of your date of birth digits. For example, if you were born in 1999, the program would output "X: the sum of digits in your date of birth are 28".

Here is my current code. I'm stuck on the part with computing the sum of the numbers.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        String inputString;
        int age;

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " + "your name");
        inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year " + "of your birth in yyyy format");

        //this is where the calculations will go//

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name + " your age is" + inputString);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's nice but what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to get this using Java 8 is:

```
inputString.chars()                             // get a stream of int with the char code point values
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)                // convert each element to its char representation
        .mapToInt(Character::getNumericValue)   // convert each char to int
        .sum();                                 // sum all elements in the stream
```

I would also recommend to validate the input to avoid exceptions. You can use a regex like:

```
if(inputString.matches("\\d{4}")){
    // do your sum
}else{
    // warn the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check each character of the year and sum its integer representation, like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
  sum += Integer.parseInt(""+inputString.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

[You can check it out on tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY4xD4IwEIV3f8WFqU0j0bFRBkdn3YxDhQrF0jbtQWIMvx1LYWB6d9@9d3etGMTeOmna6sOnqdQiBLjLgL8dgOtfWpUQUGCUwaoKOqEMuaFXpgbh6/B40tkJsDJlXI9rXUB25Jxnp2RQBiH0XaSHBbytJzNUCUU5b9O5lqbGhtA4YWw9AmkDK@BqUNbS5074IGNDsoxtw2Uj/AWJonS5NS4/fgPKLrc95i7aUBsS9yXLuBun6Q8)